# parsing stderr in php for pdf2htmlex

Tags: php, fgets, flush, stderr, proc-open

I have the below php code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8');
header( 'Content-Encoding: none; ' );

//$cmd = "pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 --override-fstype 1 --hdpi 720 --dest-dir test test/test_data/Harsh_Singh_191_Marketing_IM18.pdf";
$cmd = "ping 127.0.0.1";
$descriptorspec = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
  1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
  2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
echo "<pre>";
if (is_resource($process)) {
   while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
       print $s;
       flush();
   }
}
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

This code works fine when the $cmd is set to "ping 127.0.0.1" and it gives a php output in realtime as:

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

But the pdf2htmlEX command i.e. $cmd = "pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 --override-fstype 1 --hdpi 720 --dest-dir test test/test_data/Harsh_Singh_191_Marketing_IM18.pdf" is not working. It does convert the file and gives output in the directory, but nothing is echoed on the webpage. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

pdf2htmlex does not print any HTML output to stdout, only to files.

There are two ways to do want you want:

- Write to a temporary file first and output this file.
- Let pdf2htmlex write to a FIFO (named pipe) so your PHP script can
  read on the other side of the pipe.

I tested it with FIFO on a Linux command line, and it should work in a similar way with your PHP script, too:

```
mkfifo htmlpipe.fifo
pdf2htmlEX foo.pdf htmlpipe.fifo
```

This will block until you read from the pipe. In another terminal:

```
cat htmlpipe.fifo
<style type="text/css">...............
#sidebar {.......
```